# How to insert data in a numpy array, preserving its shape?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a collection of several data of fixed shape, and I need to store these values in an array, only creating a new dimension, so I can preserve its initial shape.

Here is a small example:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2])
values = np.array([[3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]])

n = 3

for i in range(n):
    arr = np.append(arr, values[n])
```

I need the code to output something similar to

```
>> array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
```

But I can only find

```
>> array([0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Is there a function that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy one. Reshape your `arr` into a 2d array and add an axis argument to `np.append`.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,1,2])
values = np.array([[3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]])

out = np.append(arr.reshape(1,-1),values,axis=0)
print(out)
```

Yields:

```
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

Comment: This method looks nice, but it's not exactly what I had in mind. I will need to append data to 'out' several times. But with this method, I would need to keep reshaping an ever-growing array, how could I do that?

Comment: In general, you want to avoid creating arrays multiple times. If you know the max size, you can create it and fill in values, or, more commonly, concatenate a bunch of pieces, held separately until the end: `np.concatenate([arr.reshape(1,-1),values])` - the list should contain all the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

There are various functions that all use `np.concatenate`.  `np.append` is a poorly named function that just takes 2 arguments.  It looks too much like list append, thus encouraging a iterative use such as yours.  That's not efficient.  And your problem is you didn't provide an `axis`.

In this case I prefer to use `vstack`.

```
In [24]: np.vstack((arr,values))
Out[24]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

It makes sure the first argument is 2d, i.e. `[[0,1,2]]` so that `concatenate` is happy.

`concatenate` without the dimension adjustment:

```
In [25]: np.concatenate((arr,values), axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 np.concatenate((arr,values), axis=0)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

With the adjustment.  This is essentially that `append` with `axis` does:

```
In [26]: np.concatenate((arr[None,:],values), axis=0)
Out[26]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```